# Js car script, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried everything to fix this problem. I want to make a div move like a car without using Canvas because I don't care about animation.

The problem is the div or the car doesn't actually move when I press WASD keys. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I just want it to go up, down, left and right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.grid{
    border:2px solid #333;
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
}

#box{
    background-color:DeepSkyBlue;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function()
{
   var car = document.getElementById("box");
   var carpos = car.getBoundingClientRect();
   var x = carpos.left;
   var y = carpos.right;

   car.addEventListener("keypress", keyBindOn(), false);
};

function keyBindOn(event)
{
    var code1 = event.keyCode;
    if(code1 == 87)
    {
        y -= 1;
    }

    if(code1 == 83)
    {
        y += 1;
    }

    if(code1 == 65)
    {
        x -= 1;
    }

    if(code1 == 68)
    {
        x += 1;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid"><div id="box" ></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code. Where did you get it from? `x` and `y` are not defined in your key function. You aren't updating the cars position anywhere and you should bind the event listener to something else.

Comment: Please. use switch/case statement.

Comment: *"without using Canvas because I don't care about animation"* - I'm not sure what you mean here, exactly how is that a good reason to avoid using the canvas? Also you probably want to attach your event listener to `document`. Please look at how to update an object position in CSS and note that `x` and `y` are local variables, they are not defined in `keyBindOn` and even if they where this would not do anything. You would just be changing `x` and `y` and not the objects position.

Comment: Also remove the `()` from the `car.addEventListener("keypress", keyBindOn(), false);` line, so it should look like `car.addEventListener("keypress", keyBindOn, false);`. You only want to pass in the function for now, not invoke it. The event listener will invoke it later.

Answer (score 0):

JS:

Onload:

```
var car = document.getElementById("box");
// Init these styles so on the event they exist and we can parse them for their integer values
car.style.top = '0px';
car.style.left = '0px';
// key events are attached to the document
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyBindOn, false);
```

Key function:

```
function keyBindOn(event) {
    var car = document.getElementById("box");
    // These values will come back as strings (10px) so parsing them will get us integers
    var y = parseInt(car.style.top, 10);
    var x = parseInt(car.style.left, 10);
    var code1 = event.keyCode;
    // Switch is much better than if here because it can be only one case each time.
    // Your original if would check against every value even when we had already found the one that matched.
    // This checks WASD and arrows
    switch (code1) {
        case 65:
        case 37:
            x -= 2;
            break;
        case 87:
        case 38:
            y -= 2;
            break;
        case 68:
        case 39:
            x += 2;
            break;
        case 83:
        case 40:
            y += 2;
            break;
    }

    // Reset the new styles
    car.style.top = y + 'px';
    car.style.left = x + 'px';
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5h4215aj/2/

This can be much improved but it should get you started. I did it very fast. There is much room for improvement, but I hope this helps you get started. I mostly just fixed the issues in your code and did some sloppy initialization on the "car" to make sure the inline styles existed from the get go so the key function worked.

EDIT: Didn't even realize this question was 5 months old. oops =]